# Scenario development with GAM models

Tags: r, prediction, gam

I'm working with a `mgcv::gam` model in R to generate predictions in which the relationship between time (`year`) and the outcome variable (`out`) varies.  For example, in one scenario, I'd like to force time to affect the outcome variable in a linear manner, in another a marginally decreasing manner, and in another, I'd like to specify specific slopes of the time-outcome interaction.  I'm unsure how to force the prediction to treat the interaction between time and the outcome variable in a specific manner:

```
res <- gam(out ~ s(time) + s(GEOID, bs='re'), data = df, method = "REML")
pred <- predict(gam, newdata = ndf, type="response", se=T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an interaction between`time` and `out`; here `time` has a potentially non-linear effect on `out`.

Are we talking about trying to force certain shapes for the function of `time`? If so, you will need to estimate different models; use `time` if you want a linear effect:

```
res_lin <- gam(out ~ time + s(GEOID, bs='re'), data = df, method = "REML")
```

and look at shape constrained p splines to enforce montonicity or concave/convex relationships.

The *scam* package has these sorts of constraints and uses *mgcv* with GCV smoothness selection to fit the shape constrained models.

As for specifying a specific slope for the linear effect of time, I think you'll need to include `time` as an offset in the model. So say the slope you want is 0.5 I think you need to do `+ offset(I(0.5*time))` because an offset has by definition a coefficient of 1. I would double check this though as I might have messed up my thinking here.

Comment: This is really helpful - what I'd really like to do is (1) estimate the best fitting historical model and then (2) force the time effect to have a linear shape in the future projections (so when using predict.gam()) - not sure if this is possible?  Thanks!

Comment: Also, can you add a scaling VECTOR rather than a single value?  Thanks again.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a scaling vector. For the first bit, look at the help for the b spline basis `?smooth.construct.bs.smooth.spec` as in you need to estimate with the b spline basis and appropriately set the range for the penalty to include the forecast period.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that.  The scaled vector - so instead of scaling the whole time vector by 0.5, I would scale each element of the time vector by a scaling vector of the same length.  length(scale_vector) = length(time) -so scale each element in the vector by an element in the scale_vector.